# apt-get upgrade has no errors but no effect

Tags: apt

I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version of ubuntu, it isn't working and I'm also not seeing any error messages... so I'm not really sure what the issue is or where to start looking... Any help would be appreciated.

```
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
$
```

Comment: Are you trying to upgrade to 14.04? or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### There two separate issues here:

How to **update** Ubuntu, and how to **upgrade** Ubuntu.

**Note:** *You should also NOT attempt to **upgrade**, unless you are already up-to-date (have completed **update**).*

---

### How to *update* (from command line):

**Step 1:** Update indices (to find what could be updated), then action those updates.

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**Step 2:** Action any further updates, for new / improved features.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Note:** *Your running the second part of '**Step 1**' would not do very much on its own.*

---

### How to *upgrade* (from command line):

*See link, as provided by **fkraiem** OR*

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Then, follow the on-screen instructions.

Answer (score 3):

`apt-get upgrade` does not upgrade you to a newer version of Ubuntu, it only upgrades your packages to newer versions which were released for your current version of Ubuntu. Instructions to upgrade form 12.04 to 14.04 can be found [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes#Upgrading_from_Ubuntu_12.04_LTS_or_Ubuntu_13.10).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to upgrade to the latest version of ubuntu you need to use `sudo do-release-upgrade` as `sudo apt-get upgrade` only updates all packages already installed on your system to the latest version.